# Re-route Midi from one program to another

Tags: audio, music, midi

I have a (closed-source) program on Windows which is able to output music as Midi.

I want to write software, to be run on the same PC, which uses this Midi data as input.

I figured I could do this by routing a physical wire from a Midi-out port on the PC to a Midi-in port, and monitoring this port with my program.

However, is it possible to route the Midi output from the program to my custom software without using hardware? I imagine I could use a 'fake Midi card' which would pretend to be a Midi sound card which the Windows software would route the music to.

Does anything like this exist? Or is the only way the hardware route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is a loopback adapter (this terminology comes from networking).

I found this with a google search: http://www.sionsoft.com/hubi.html

Don't know how it works, but you can also search for other MIDI Loopback Drivers.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - I've just found a whole load: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=Loopback+MIDI